# Gitkit token service API returns 403 "cannot be identified with a client project" error

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I am currently trying to use the Google Identity Toolkit Token Service REST API (https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/reference/securetoken/rest/v1/token) to generate an access token which I can use in my backend server.

When I specifying "authorization_code" as "grant_type" and the gtoken cookie value after authentication as "code" in the POST request to https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token, I get a 403 response with the following error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I inspected the gtoken value via a JWT decoder and it looks to be correct in format. In particular I can see that aud is set to my application/client ID. The documentation doesn't say anything about specifying API key - usually I would expect that to be specified in the Authorization header. So I am not sure what I am missing here.

Any pointer to this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An API key in the URL is required when calling Google Identity Toolkit APIs (including the Token Service API). However, I would suggest you take a look at the new version of the service -  [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). The Firebase Auth SDK has build-in support of the Token Service API.